# React Native Elements rounded FAB

Tags: floating-action-button, react-native-elements

Im using **React Native Elements**, and I want a rounded **FAB**, but it shows a square **FAB**:

```
import { FAB } from 'react-native-elements';

<FAB
    icon={{
      name: 'add',
      size: 30,
      color: 'white',
    }}
    placement="right"
/>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: I have this same problem. Did you ever discover the answer?

Comment: Hi Zack, nope, I switched to React Native Paper

Comment: Hey, can you please create an issue on repo?

Answer (score 0):

try adding buttonStyle={{borderRadius:1000,}}

```
<FAB
icon={{
  name: 'add',
  size: 30,
  color: 'white',
}}
placement="right"
buttonStyle={{borderRadius:1000,}} />
```